# Hotkey for selecting transform manipulator type

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

Is there a hotkey or shortcut to change the type of the active transform manipulator?

[image]

[This site](http://archive.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-237a/3d-transform-manipulators/index.html) lists

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for translate
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for rotation
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> for scale

none of which work for me. Are these the correct current shortcuts?

Comment: Ok, i swear there used to be a something+space hotkey that popped up a menu which you could then click or hit 1,2,3 to pick from, but all i can find about manipulators at all is the one to toggle it on and off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First what you linked to is for blender version **2.37** not 2.73, so the shortcuts are wrong.

To add a shortcut to switch the manipulator type; open up the user preferences.
Under the *Input* tab add a new shortcut under *3D View* > *3D View (Global)*. Type `view3d.enable_manipulator` in to the identifier field, then just check one of the grayed out boxes for *Translate*, *Scale*, and *Rotate*. The only hard part will be finding 3 unused shortcuts to use for the new transform manipulator shortcuts.
[image: user preferences]

Other transform manipulator shortcuts:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> is the default shortcut to toggle on and of the transform manipulator.
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> open a menu to change the orientation type.
When using the buttons in the 3D view header, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> allows for more then one  manipulator type to be active at a time.

Comment: Ha, that's a big difference isn't it :P (2.37!=2.73)

Comment: Seems a fair bit has changed since then! :D

Comment: I ended up using ALT+ Numpad 1 for Translate, ALT+ Numpad 2 for Rotate, ALT + Numpad 3 for Scale. Also, ALT+ Numpad 0 to toggle Manipulator (even though default is CTRL + Spacebar)

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the multiple manipulator option with Shift! I find that very useful!

Comment: How do we do this in 2.79?