# Is there any manipulator Shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

is there any shortcut for manipulators (move,rotate,scale) ? i want to use single axis with manipulator handler. i do not want to use key combinations like G, X.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... If I understand correctly, you want a shortcut to call a manipulator, then specify a single axis on which to manipulate. How is that different from `G`, `X`?

Comment: No there is no single hotkey, you need to use combination of 2.

Comment: i want to change manipulator from Move to Rotate with one key. When i animate something i need this.

Comment: See this answer:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19352/hotkey-for-selecting-transform-manipulator-type