# Hot Key responsible for changing manipulator doesn't work

Tags: transforms, shortcut, documentation, 3d-manipulator

As I was reading through Blender [Documentation 2.4](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Manipulators), looking for hot keys. And suddenly found an interesting one. So I went to Blender to test it myself. Though it didn't work for me. The Hot key I am talking about, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, which is used to change the manipulator to either *Translate, Rotate or Scale*. I am wondering why is the hot key not working for me,

**Did it get disabled in the newer versions of blender**(btw i'm using blender v2.76)**, is the hot key conflicting with a new feature added, or is it just me?**

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19352/hotkey-for-selecting-transform-manipulator-type

Comment: I just tried it, it's not working for me either, I'm using B 2.76.

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov a lot of things have changed since 2.4. Think of that version as a very outdated one. While some concepts are similar don't count on the documentation for anything else than archaeological curiosity...