# Display rotate manipulator controls?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

Is it possible to set up Blender to have rotation controllers similar to Maya?

Preview of Maya's rotation controllers:

[image: Maya rotate]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just enable the '*Transform Manipulator*' in the 3D header:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will toggle the *Transform Manipulator* on or off. You can also <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the options beside the *Transform Manipulator* option to show the Location, Rotation and Scale controls at the same time.

For blender 2.8 the manipulator section is on the toolbox on left of the screen (if you can't see it press <kbd>T</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: @Animatoring Not that I can see from looking, but if you have the 'pie menus' add-on enabled, pressing Ctrl+Space will bring up a menu to choose which transform widget to enable instead of just turning it on or off.

Comment: Is there a hotkey to quickly turn on/off the transform manipulators for move, rotate, or scale? For example you have the transform manipulators on and are using scale but want to switch to rotate with the manipulators on? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ray, by default Maya autos to having the transform manipulators on but they only have whichever currently used on. I was curious if they had something like that in Blender.

Comment: I have just found [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19352/hotkey-for-selecting-transform-manipulator-type) which should help with setting up shortcuts like maya.

Answer (score 3):

In 2.8+, enabling and disabling of these graphical manipulator controls has moved into the Gizmos dropdown (tooltip: Show gizmos of all types) of the 3D Viewport.

The enable boxes are in the sub-section titled "Object Gizmos" for which there are checkboxes:  Move, Scale, and Rotate.

[image]