# Translate manipulator switched to blocks and does not work

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-manipulator

I think I accidentally hit a weird shortcut to make it like this but still can not find the shortcut, now instead of translating it transforms. I can not move anything around unless I just drag it. Does anyone know what to do to fix this?

[image: manipulator in the 3D view]

Answer (score 4):

You've set the transformation manipulator type to *Scale*.
[image]

Change it to ***Translate***. Remember you can enable all the types by clicking on the icons with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
[image]

Comment: I'm new to blender and still trying to get used to it, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you :). BTW you can also set the custom shortcut to switch between manipulator types quickly. Please see this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19352/hotkey-for-selecting-transform-manipulator-type